# I Need to have a field where you can show an hour in Sharepoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I have a website in Sharepoint 2007. I need to create a page where I have a field where the user can enter an hour (22:00, for example). I will then make some CAML queries, asking to get the pages with the hour less or greater than a specific hour.

I know Sharepoint have the Datetimefield, but this one only shows the date, you cannot set the hour.

Some solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm missing something here.... But can't you just store the hour in a plain Int field data type and CAML query on that?

Comment: No, because it could be at 22:15 hours or 18:30 hours